# How to add conditional date filter to SQLite export script

Tags: bash, date, sqlite

I am using a bash script to export data from the songs table in a Clementine db:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/sqlite3 /home/username/.config/Clementine/clementine.db <<!
.headers off
.mode csv
select filename from songs where lastplayed > -1;
!
```

The date information shown in the column `lastplayed` is expressed in unix time (example:1479607204). Where a record has no date, the field's data is shown as -1.

Using the above script correctly displays all entries in the songs table that have *any* lastplayed date (lastplayed > -1).

If instead, I want the date filtered based on number of days elapsed (using today's date, so assume the NOW statement is used in some way), how would I modify the SELECT line above to calculate and filter output?  I reviewed the [SQLite manual page for date/time](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) but as a newbie I could not solve how to use its syntax in the script.

Assume the filter lists only those records for which there is a date, and the unix date is at least 10 calendar days earlier than today.

Answer (score 0):

To do comutations with dates, add the appropriate modifiers to some date function. To convert a date into the Unix format, use `strftime()` with the `%s` format:

```sql
sqlite> SELECT strftime('%s', 'now', '-3 days');
1479410717
```

And to make the comparison work, you have to convert the resulting string into a number:

```sql
SELECT filename
FROM songs
WHERE lastplayed > CAST(strftime('%s', 'now', '-3 days') AS INTEGER);
```

Comment: This helped enough to figure it out - many thanks.  Here is the script change that solved:  
select filename, lastplayed
from songs
where lastplayed between 0 and cast(strftime('%s', 'now', '-10 days') as integer);